# How to change size of remote ssh session in my terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal

I use the "Terminal" app. for SSH'ing to my Ubuntu VPS. The problem I have is that the width/size of the remote terminal doesn't fill my Terminal app. window, only part.

How can I make it fill the entire Terminal area?

Answer (score 3):

What is you terminal application ? running on what OS ?

Perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
eval $(resize)
```

Comment: yes, OS X Terminal app, but i think it depends on remote machine, cause i use few vps's and only with this one i have this issue.

Comment: Your comment helps me a lot, i found that i need xterm package, after installing it everything works fine. Thanks.